# Make Windows 8.1 & 10 File Explorer open in "This PC" view

Tags: windows, windows-8, windows-8.1, windows-10, windows-explorer

Up until the recent Windows 8.1 update, I used this guide and it worked flawlessly:

http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/quick-tip-make-windows-8-file-explorer-launch-in-computer-view/7550/

Now however, recent updates have disabled/grayed out the 'Target' input field of the File Explorer properties menu. This old method is therefore rendered useless and I cannot figure out a new method to get File Explorer to open 'This PC' by default.

P.S. I have tried the method of creating a shorcut linked to 'This PC' and Pinning it to the taskbar, but this has completely different behavior than the original File Explorer shortcut.

*Update*: Answer now reflects the new Windows 10 method.