# How do I make Windows 10's File Explorer open "This PC" by default?

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, windows-10-preview

I know how to do that on Windows Vista and Windows 7, and I know how to do that on Windows 8 and Windows 8.1, but neither of the ways work with Windows 10; it always defaults into the "Home" view.

(I am basically reposting [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/742878/make-windows-8-1-file-explorer-open-in-this-pc-view) for Windows 10.)

Answer (score 455, accepted):

As of build 9926 (at least - it may have been an earlier build), this is configurable via the GUI.

Open Explorer and go to **View**, then click **Options** (or **Change folder and search options**). In **General** tab you can change **Open File Explorer** to *This PC*

[image]

Comment: Still working on final build 10240.

Comment: There was no "general" in my menu, but it opened after I clicked on the icon above the text "Options". Using W10 Pro.

Comment: @Arda - 'General' is the name of the tab the option is on.

Comment: Oh I see it now, thanks @Taz for the clarification!

Comment: Still working as of 8/20/2015 for Windows 10 RTM.

Comment: Any way to do this for a user's home? e.g. "C:/Users/Bob"

Comment: This works perfect on the release version too .

Comment: Still works on 1511, build 10548.164. I migrated to SU just to upvote

Comment: Works on 10 1607

Comment: I consider this quite a design mistake by Microsoft. "Of course, let's put the file explorer settings in the folder options." ... Furthermore I want to open a complete different folder, for this you need a hack again, so why not give us an input field as an option. // Autohotkey to the rescue.

Answer (score 33):

The **registry** setting that controls this behavior is the `DWORD` value name `LaunchTo` under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Advanced`

Set the `DWORD` accordingly:

```
1 = This PC
2 = Quick access
```

Comment: When there is a way to do it through the UI normally, tinkering with registry seems excessive and dangerous.

Comment: @ANeves However, it's useful if you want to do something programmatically, which is why I included it here.

Answer (score 10):

**Win 8.1:**

If you don't use Libraries at all, you can hide them. This makes your default "This PC".

1. In File Explorer, select the View tab and click the Options button.
2. In the General tab, under Navigation Pane, uncheck "View Libraries"
3. Click OK, then restart File Explorer.

**Win 10:**

1. In File Explorer, select the View tab and click the Options button.
2. Look at "Open File Explorer to:" and click the dropdown.
3. Select 'This PC'
4. Click OK.

Comment: I have another path that I would like to change the target to, your first solution doesn't help with that, and the second isn't an option on 8.1, any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Right-clicking in the left navigation panel will offer you several options to:

- Show favorites
- Show Libraries
- Show all folders
- Expand to current folder

I never liked my Explorer opening to Libraries, and so prefer the current look of My PC.

Answer (score 1):

**Well, basically you can delete everything in 'Home' and attach 'This Pc' into it.**

So it's more like a feature, right?

1. Press <kbd>Windows</kbd> and type `regedit`
2. Right-click and open **As Administrator**
3. Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HomeFolder\NameSpace\DelegateFolders`
4. Delete everything there (Looks like `{2141241-BLABLA}`)
5. Right-click on **DelegateFolders** click **New** and choose **Key**
6. Name the new key **{20D04FE0-3AEA-1069-A2D8-08002B30309D}**
7. Select the new key and double-click the **(Default)** entry
8. In *Value Data* type `This PC`

The result looks like this:
[image]

Comment: Does not work for me. "Home" is now empty but still opens as default. What version did you do it on? I am using the 32-bit non-Enterprise.

Comment: i heard from another source that this was configurable in the latest build (1/23/2015) but i couldn't find it. Anyone hear about this?

Comment: When there is a way to do it through the UI normally, tinkering with registry seems excessive and dangerous.

Comment: @ANeves This information may be useful to some. It's up to each individual to decide which method they are comfortable with. There are often many ways to skin a cat.