# How do I fix Windows Explorer shortcuts always opening to "This PC" or "Quick access"?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I'm stumped on this one...
Recently my Windows 10 install has started opening all Windows Explorer shortcuts/links straight to "This PC" (or Quick Access depending on [this setting](https://superuser.com/questions/819521/how-do-i-make-windows-10s-file-explorer-open-this-pc-by-default)).  The will not open to the address specified.  e.g. - If there's a folder shortcut to the Downloads folder, double clicking it opens This PC.

How do I get them working correctly again?

Comment: Does it work if you type the folder path in Run dialog? My guess is the folder association settings are broken somehow. Try "folder" and "directory" association reg fixes from [here](http://www.winhelponline.com/blog/file-association-fixes-windows-10/)

Comment: Tried them... didn't work.  Interestingly, if the shortcut is a Quick Access folder then that folder is highlighted under the Folders section of This PC.  Weird.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your latest note on Quick access. Is there a screenshot you can post?

Comment: So I think this was an issue with Windows 10 preview edition.  It updated yesterday to a new release and Explorer started working as expected again.  Thanks for the help w32sh.

Comment: Nice! Glad it's now fixed.